# How can I subset data with R to maximize diversity across each of multiple columns?

Tags: r, sample, sampling

I have a data frame with 10,966 rows and 10 columns. I want to sample from this data frame using R to get ~500 samples, maximizing the diversity of unique values from each column. Running `data %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)` on this dataset gives the following output showing the number of distinct values per column (note the ID column shows all distinct rows, each with an ID).

| ID | A | B | C | D | E | F | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10966 | 2055 | 69 | 132 | 9 | 167 | 1336 | 12 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

Whilst it won't be possible to capture the full diversity from each column (especially with some columns having > 500 unique values), is there an approach that could allow me to maximize the diversity in the sample?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73477082/6574038) help you?

Comment: Do you want to select based on unique values or it could be based on variance (i.e. select those columns with the highest variance)?

Comment: @Rina I'd like to select based on unique values, maximising these for for each column

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution is to cluster the data into as many clusters as you want to take samples, and then sample a single random point from each cluster. The result is a cluster-stratified random sampling. By using complete linkage clustering, this procedure should maximize the overall variance of your sample, while minimizing the amount of singleton clusters.

See below for code with a dummy example.

```r
require("tidyverse")

# Create data
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
k <- 50
df <- tibble(A = sample(rnorm(2055), n, replace = T),
             B = sample(rnorm(69), n, replace = T),
             C = sample(rnorm(132), n, replace = T),
             D = sample(c("1", "2", "3"), n, replace = T) %>% as.factor())

# Create dummy variables for D
df <- df %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = D, values_from = dummy, values_fill = 0, names_prefix = "D_")

# Calculate distances and divide into k groups
d <- dist(df)
hc <- hclust(d, method = "complete")
c <- cutree(hc, k = k)

# Select a single representative from each group
df <- df %>%
  mutate(cluster = c,
         ID = row_number())
df_sub <- df %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1)

# Plot PCA to check if sampled evenly
pcdat <- df %>%
  select(!c(ID, cluster)) %>%
  prcomp()
pcdat$x %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(ID = row.names(.),
         selected = ifelse(ID %in% df_sub$ID, "Yes", "No")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = PC1,
             y = PC2,
             colour = selected,
             shape = selected)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(Yes = 16, No = 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great! It works wonderfully and has increased the diversity for those higher-diversity columns a lot. Thank you

Comment: Glad it works for you! I forgot to mention that when applying this to your own data, you probably want to center and scale each column before calculating the Euclidean distances.